# Passing Additional Parameters to add_filter Callable

Tags: filters, hooks, cookies

I have an `add_filter` function for the `auth_cookie_expiration` hook. This hook accepts three parameters. However, I am interested in passing it more parameters. For example:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'get_expiration', 10, 5 );
```

This would be possible with `apply_filter`, but the `add_filter` function is called once, which makes it throw an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_expiration(), 3 passed in ... and exactly 5 expected
```

I got around this using closures, but it seems like a completely ridiculous way to do this:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', function() use ($param1, $param2) { return get_expiration(null, null, null, $param1, $param2); } , 10, 3 );
```

Is there a proper/more elegant way to make it accept additional parameters (even better, the params I want in place of the default ones)? Am I misunderstanding how `add_filter` is supposed to work?

For the sake of example, suppose `get_expiration` looks like this:

```
function get_expiration( $length, $user_id, $remember, $param1, $param2 )
{
    return $param1 + $param2;
}
```

Comment: you cannot modify the argument numbers then the use of `use` looks like the better solution.

Comment: what is not elegant about closures? by miles better than creating an object for this or using globals.

Comment: They're not inelegant in principle (on the contrary), just in this case: basically I'm creating a function within a one-liner just to call another function. It's a pretty dirty workaround for having to use a hook that doesn't handle such cases. But here I suspect I am simply missing something, and that WordPress has thought of such a scenario. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter in `add_filter` is a function with **accepted arguments**, not returned values.

This is an example how I pass my custom array `$args` to change an existing array `$filter_args`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', function( $filter_args ) use ( $args ) {
        return eswc_var_dropdown_args( $filter_args, $args );
    }
);

function eswc_var_dropdown_args( $filter_args, $args ) {
    $filter_args['show_option_none'] = $args['var_select_text'];
    return $filter_args;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Am I misunderstanding how add_filter is supposed to work?

Yes, you are.

The function ( aka callback function ), specified by name, in the second parameter of `add_filter()`, **NEVER** passes **ANY** parameters. It accepts parameters passed by `apply_filters()`. The number of these parameters, and their meaning is defined by `apply_filters()`. The callback function **MUST** accept at least the first parameter, past the hook name. It **MUST**, also,  return modified ( or not ) value for this first parameter.

Comment: What would be a good way for this user to access an additional variable ( not originally passed to the function ) inside the callback?

Answer (score 0):

After just using my original "solution" for a while, I have returned to this problem with a bit more time to figure out what WordPress actually does.

Firstly it should be noted that to directly pass a parameter to an `add_filter` function, the only reasonable way is the one in my original question.

However, more often than not, it is possible to solve the larger problem better by passing a parameter to the function calling `apply_filters` in WordPress or the plugin you're trying to hook into.

For example, `apply_filters( 'auth_cookie_expiration' )`, in any meaningful way for hooking, is called in WordPress inside `wp_set_auth_cookie`, which accepts the same parameters ( `$user_id, $remember` ), so calling `wp_set_auth_cookie()` (likely done anyway for any session manipulation) allows the eventual passing of parameters to `add_filter`. For example:

```
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', array( 'get_session_expiration' ), 10, 3 );

// ...

wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, $is_remember_me );

// ...

function get_session_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    // ...
    return $some_calculated_expiration;
}
```

This works in multiple cases I have found where filter hooks are available.